# Leaflet move single point of polygon in GeoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have leaflet with a geoJSON layer group and load several geoJSON features, each as a separate layer added to the geoJSON layer group.  For a given selected layer, I need to move a point of the polygon on that layer using javascript.  So, for example, I may need to move the 3rd vertex to 30.123, -80.123.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  I can move a marker easily with the setLatLng() method but I can't find anything to change a polygon point.

Here is an example of how I am creating the map and adding my geoJSON features:

```
   function createMap(){ 
    myMap = L.map('locationMap', {
                editable: true,
                attributionControl: false,
                fullscreenControl: true,
                fullscreenControlOptions: {
                    position: 'topleft'
                }
            }).setView([@Model.MapCenterLat, @Model.MapCenterLong], @Model.MapInitialZoom);

    L.tileLayer('@Model.MapUrl2', {
        drawControl: true,
        maxZoom: 20,
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(myMap);

    geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(myMap);

    loadGeoFences('');
}

function loadGeoFences(parentId) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetGeoFences")';

    $.get(url, { parentId: parentId },
        function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    var newLayer = L.geoJson(value,
                        {
                            onEachFeature: applyLayerStyle
                        });
                    newLayer.addTo(geoJsonLayer);
                });
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using the leaflet.editing plugin.  Once you have the correct layer, the layer.editing.latlngs array can be modified with the desired coordinates.  Then call layer.redraw() to update the polygon.

Answer (score -2):

You can change the latlngs while geoJson loading with following:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if(layer instanceof L.Polyline){
      var latlngs = layer.getLatLngs()
      var ll = latlngs[0][2];
      ll.lat = 51.490056
      latlngs[0][2] = ll;
      layer.setLatLngs(latlngs);
    }
}


L.geoJSON(json,{onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/hvdxo3z7/